# Does there exist a set such that $X \in X$?

Tags: set-theory

In Russell's paradox, if there is a set that has everything as an element, it can be seen that it is a contradiction. I think if there is a set X such that $X \in X$, there is contradiction. I want to prove this by axiom of regularity but i cannot. How to prove this?

Comment: Perhaps begin by stating the Axiom of Regularity.  Then, assuming you have such a set $X$, try to fit it in that statement.

Comment: 1. Russell's paradox does not arise from a universal set; though there *are* paradoxes that arise from the existence of a universal set. 2. You do need regularity (there are set theories that do not have the axiom of regularity in which there *do* exist sets that are elements of themselves).  3. To determine how to prove this using the Axiom of Regularity, it would be helpful to know exactly what version of the Axiom of Regularity you are using.

Comment: The proof is given on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity). (Look at the first section on elementary implications of regularity.)